# Finding controls in Windows Forms C# .NET?

Tags: winforms

Using Windows Forms, two link labels are created dynamically. When the user clicks on anyone of links labels, one dynamic form is created. In that form I created one data grid, a text box and a button placed dynamically (in that dynamic form). Now I want to access the dynamic data grid in the dynamic button click event. How can I do that?

```
private void Users_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("Usp_Get_Employees", con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string somecode = i.ToString() + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["eid"].ToString();
            LinkLabel  lbluser  = new LinkLabel();
            lbluser.Name =  ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["eid"].ToString();
            lbluser.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ename"].ToString();
            lbluser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, i * 40);
            lbluser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 30);
            Controls.Add(lbluser);
            lbluser.Click += new EventHandler(lbluser_Click);
        }
    }
}


void lbluser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkLabel lnkClis = (LinkLabel)sender;
    Form frm = new Form();
    frm.Name = lnkClis.Name;
    frm.Text = lnkClis.Text;
    frm.Show();

    DataGrid dtgrd = new DataGrid();
    dtgrd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 1 * 40);
    dtgrd.Name = lnkClis.Name;
    names = lnkClis.Name;

    TextBox tx = new TextBox();

    tx.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 5 * 40);
    tx.Size = new Size(80, 30);
    tx.Multiline = true;
    tx.LostFocus += new EventHandler(tx_LostFocus);

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 7 * 40);
    btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 30);
    btn.Name = lnkClis.Name;
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

    frm.Controls.Add(dtgrd);
    frm.Controls.Add(tx);
    frm.Controls.Add(btn);
}

// Now I am trying to access the data grid in the btn_click event

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btsave = (Button)sender;
    string eid = btsave.Name;

    object grd = btsave.Parent.Controls.Find("dtgrd", true).FirstOrDefault();

    ((DataGrid)grd).DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Now I am getting an error object set of instances of an object at:

```
((DataGrid)grd).DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message you have written:

> Now I am getting an error object set of instances of an object at

makes no sense, but it looks like

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If this is the case, I think the error lays in `Find` method call. According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx):

> Searches for controls by their Name property and builds an array of all the controls that match.

In your button click handler you assume that grid is called **dtgrd**, but while you create a grid you name it like this:

```
dtgrd.Name = lnkClis.Name;
```

it will suffice if you change this line to:

```
dtgrd.Name = "dtgrd";
```

Having said that, you should consider using an anonymous method for the button click handler. It will eliminate need for calling the `Find` method in the first place.

```
 void lbluser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //...
    DataGrid dtgrd = new DataGrid();
   //...
    Button btn = new Button();
   //...
    btn.Click += (sender,args)=> dtgrd.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much i got it. thank you for giving response Mr. Rafal

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
    public Form1()
    {
        Form f1 = new Form();

        f1.Text = "New Form";

        TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
        t1.Top = 0;
        t1.Name = "t1";
        t1.Visible = true;
        f1.Controls.Add(t1);

        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1.Top = 30;
        b1.Name = "b1";
        b1.Text = "Click";
        b1.Click += b1_Click;
        f1.Controls.Add(b1);

        f1.Show();
    }

    public void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        object txt = btn.Parent.Controls.Find("t1", false).First();
        ((TextBox)txt).Text = "Hi, you have clicked me.";
    }
```

Comment: hi nithesh, in the above case working fine , but when i take datagrid it is showing error. My code is :                    object grd = btsave.Parent.Controls.Find("dtgrd", false).FirstOrDefault();  ((DataGrid)grd).DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Answer (score 1):

I modified Nitesh's code a bit. Just capture the textbox in the click handler using a lambda:

```
public Form1()
{
    Form f1 = new Form();

    f1.Text = "New Form";

    TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
    t1.Top = 0;
    t1.Name = "t1";
    t1.Visible = true;
    f1.Controls.Add(t1);

    Button b1 = new Button();
    b1.Top = 30;
    b1.Name = "b1";
    b1.Text = "Click";
    b1.Click += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("The text is: " + t1.Text);
    f1.Controls.Add(b1);

    f1.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is from the statement (as the `grd` object is `null`):

```
((DataGrid)grd).DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Since you are trying to catch hold of a dynamic control, it's good have a proper null checks, type checks, and error handling. Something like this:

```
if(grd != null && grd is DataGrid)
    ((DataGrid)grd).DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: please add formatting to your code, it will make it more readable